# C++ STL vector erase

Tags: c++, vector, stl

The problem is that when I run the function it crashes at the `erase` part and I cant figure out why.

```
void Grupa::del() {
    int size = studenti.size();
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        if (studenti[i].materia1<5 && studenti[i].materia2<5 && studenti[i].materia3<5) {
        studenti.erase(studenti.begin()+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the [Erase-remove Idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you erase an element, the vector gets smaller; but you're still using the original size, and falling off the end. Also, you don't want to increment `i` after erasing, otherwise you'll skip the element after the erased one. So you want something like:

```
for (size_t i = 0; 
     i != studenti.size(); // don't hoist out of the loop
     /* don't increment here */) 
{
    if (...) {
        studenti.erase(studenti.begin()+i);
    } else {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Or see other answers for the "erase-remove" idiom, which is a nice, and perhaps more efficient, way of avoiding this kind of error-prone logic.

Comment: +1. Nitpick: technically it should be vector<t>::size_type rather than std::size_t.

Comment: @BillyONeal: `vector<t>::size_type` is `std::size_t`, since the vector uses the default allocator, which defines it thusly. If you want to account for the possiblity of a non-standard allocator, then you'd need either `the_allocator::size_type` or `decltype(studenti.size())`.

Comment: @Andrew: No, that would give `int` to match the integer literal.

Comment: @Mike: That's why it is an uber nitpick :)

Comment: @MikeSeymour: could you please explain why? I though auto will be substituted with the actual underlying type of the `students.size()`

Comment: @Andrew: It's substituted with the type of the initialiser, which is `0` not `studenti.size()`.

Comment: (Although it would be better to use iterators, or algorithms that manage the iteration for you. But I wanted to stay close to the original code; I just couldn't bring myself to keep the `int`).

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you should be using an STL algorithm, `std::remove_if`, instead of this, which conveniently avoids the problems other answerers have pointed out already. Consider this instead:

```
studenti.erase(std::remove_if(studenti.cbegin(), studenti.cend(), [](Student const& currentStudent) {
    return currentStudent.materia1<5 && currentStudent.materia2<5 && currentStudent.materia3<5;
}), studenti.cend());
```

Note that this has the advantage over your solution in that it takes linear time relative to the number of elements in the vector, while the for/erase solution takes quadratic time.

Answer (score 0):

`i` goes beyond the size of the vector. Due to the `erase` calls the size of the vector gets smaller, but you go until the saved size, which is greater than the actual if there were erased items.

This is why `erase` returns an iterator, it is a valid iterator to the element next to the erased one:

```
for (auto it = studenti.begin(); it != studenti.end();) {
    if (it->materia1<5 && it->materia2<5 && it->materia3<5)
        it = studenti.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

Comment: The OP probably wants `cbegin` and `cend` for this particular application.